# Can there be RGB and CMYK in a document at the same time?

Tags: color

I know, that when you create a PDF, you can easily have some elements as RGB and some as CMYK. But is it also possible, that the same element (e.g. a background) has both definitions in a PDF and depending on the driver (screen or printer) the RGB or CMYK definition is used.

So I know, that when we use xcolor, you can say

```
\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
```

or

```
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
```

but this definitely changes which color scope is used. So when we defined

```
\definecolor{Black}{RGB/CMYK}{0,0,0/0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0}
```

either one or the other is used. But can also both be used in the PDF depending on the purpose?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. There are multiple ways of doing this. First, it's the default. If you load just `\usepackage{xcolor}`, every color will be saved in the way you specified it. Only if we explicitly request a colormodel through `[rgb]` or `[cmyk]` everything gets converted into a uniform model.

You can also change the model all colors get converted to by issuing `\selectcolormodel{...}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{BlueRGB}{RGB}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{BlueCMYK}{CMYK}{1,1,0,0}
\begin{document}
\color{BlueRGB} This is in RGB.

\color{BlueCMYK} This is in CMYK.

\selectcolormodel{CMYK}
\color{BlueRGB} Still CMYK.

\color{BlueCYMK} Still CMYK.

\selectcolormodel{RGB}
\color{BlueCMYK} Now we are back to RGB.

\color{BlueRGB} Nothing changed.

\selectcolormodel{natural}
\color{BlueCMYK} We are again in CMYK territory.

\color{BlueRGB} And back to RGB.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Marcel Krüger for your explanation. As I mentioned I know, that there can be CMYK and RGB in a document at the same time. However with my example of ``\definecolor{Black}{RGB/CMYK}{0,0,0/0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0}`` is there a way to preserve both color definitions for the same element and let the driver displaying/printing the PDF decide?