# Drawing a color swatch/palette for CMYK

Tags: color, boxes

**Background**

I wish to create a LaTeX version of a color palette similar to the one found here: https://codepen.io/devi8/pen/nJMGZR. It looks like this:

[image]

I have managed to find code to build on, but I am stuck on two issues:

1. How do I use CMYK instead of RGB in the MWE?
2. How can I divide each box into two boxes and add a shadow border to each?

**Minimal Working Example (MWE)**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,stackengine}

\newcommand\palbox[2]{{\sffamily\fboxsep=10pt\relax\fboxrule=0pt\relax\footnotesize%
  \fcolorbox{gray!50}{gray!10}{%
    \stackengine{8pt}{%
      \colorbox[RGB]{#1}{\rule{60pt}{0pt}\rule{0pt}{60pt}}%
    }{%
      \color{black!60}\stackengine{6pt}{\##2}{\saycolors{#1}}{U}{l}{F}{F}{S}%
    }{U}{l}{F}{F}{S}%
  }%
}}

\newcommand\saycolors[1]{\saycolorsaux#1\relax}
\def\saycolorsaux#1 #2 #3\relax{R:#1 G:#2 B:#3}

\begin{document}
    \palbox{1 103 143}{01678f}\quad
    \palbox{221 109 16}{dd6d10}\quad
    \palbox{18 54 69}{123645}\quad
    \palbox{120 121 124}{78797c}
\end{document}
```

**Current output**

[image]

**Desired output**

Two CMYK colors next to each other in one box with shadow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a solution based on your code but based on `tcolorbox`. I'm not an expert in color systems, so I don't know if CMYK works properly here.

**EDIT:** Color name and CMYK code are now separate. `tcbraster` to put swatches in columns and rows.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{array,tabularx,colortbl}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newcommand{\swatch}[5]{%
    \definecolor{c1}{cmyk}{#1}%
    \definecolor{c2}{cmyk}{#3}%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        enhanced,
        frame hidden,
        width=21ex,
        clip upper,
        fontupper=\color{gray},
        colback=white,
        fuzzy shadow={0mm}{0pt}{-.5pt}{1pt}{black!60!white},
        tabularx={XX}
    ]
        \cellcolor{c1} & \cellcolor{c2} \\[4ex]
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textsf{#5}\rule{0pt}{3ex}} \\
        {\tiny\textsf{#2}} & {\tiny\textsf{#4}}
    \end{tcolorbox}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2,raster force size=false]
\swatch{.61,.34,0,.07}{blue1}{.66,.38,0,.14}{blue2}{Blue Jeans}
\swatch{0,.19,.67,0}{yellow1}{0,.24,.73,.04}{yellow2}{Sunflower}
\swatch{.25,0,.51,.17}{green1}{.27,0,.58,.24}{green2}{Grass}
\swatch{0,.64,.57,.07}{red1}{0,.69,.62,.15}{red2}{Grapefruit}
\end{tcbraster}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks fantastic, is there a. way to get the two swatches next to each other without a line break? And is it possible to define the color and the text separately?

Comment: @kexxcream I extended my answer

Comment: Great, one final issues. I'm using CMYK for in the `\documentclass` and the color are not rendered good. Is it possible to force `\definecolor` to use RGB?

Comment: Solved the above issue thanks to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/537188/can-there-be-rgb-and-cmyk-in-a-document-at-the-same-time. The solution was to use `\selectcolormodel{RGB}` to change color model.