# Confused about mixing colors in tikz / xcolor

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I noticed first that `yellow!50!green` did not produce the same color as `green!50!yellow`. Then I tried more systematically:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach\y in {0,10,...,100} {
\fill[green!\y!yellow] (.1*\y,0) rectangle ++(1,1);
\fill[yellow!\y!green] (.1*\y,2) rectangle ++(1,1);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This is what I get:
[image: mix green and yellow]

What exactly is going on there?

Comment: Load the package `xcolor` before `tikz` with an option other than `natural`, say `rgb` or `cmyk` depending on your document. Then the colors will mix properly. (Green comes from rgb, yellow from cmyk.)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel In light of the existing answer, could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @Teepeemm I'm working on something. I'm not an expert on colors and color models and color conversion but I have solutions. (The easiest one would be to chose one or the other …)

Comment: Or not. Muzimuzhi has basically posted what I had worked on. Let me leave some links to related Q&A: [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9973), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/537216)

Comment: You mix green!y with yellow, and yellow!y with green. It‘s not symmetrical by syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `xcolor` uses color model `natural` by default.
   (See `xcolor` package doc, Table 1: "Package options".)
2. In `natural` color model, `green` is in `rgb` model and `yellor` is in `cmyk` model.
   (Can only be checked clearly from source code ([1](https://github.com/latex3/xcolor/blob/849682246582946835d28c8f9b2081ff2c340e09/xcolor.dtx#L7064) and [2](https://github.com/latex3/xcolor/blob/849682246582946835d28c8f9b2081ff2c340e09/xcolor.dtx#L7081)), but the Figure 4: "Target color model" in package doc tells the difference a bit.)
3. In a color mix expression like `<name1>!<pct>!<name2>` (`<pct>` is short for percent), if `<name1>` and `<name2>` are in different color models, in normal case when 0 < `<pct>` < 100 the resulting color has the same model with `<name1>`.
   (See `xcolor` package doc, sec. 2.3.2 "Meaning of standard color expressions", the note paragraph after numbered list.)
4. Specifically, if `<pct>` is 0, `<name2>` is returned, without model transformation.  In this case, the resulting color has the same model with `<name2>`, not `<name1>`.
   (ditto)

To set or change current color model, one of the following ways can be used:

- Use `\PassOptionsToPackage{<model>}{xcolor}` before `xcolor` is loaded.
- Use model name as package option, for example `\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}`.
- Use `\selectcolormodel{<model>}` after `xcolor` is loaded.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\printColorSpec}[1]{%
  \textcolor{#1}{\rule{1em}{1em}} 
  \extractcolorspec{#1}{\temp}%
  \makebox[4cm][l]{\detokenize{"#1"}} ->
  \detokenize\expandafter{\temp}\par
}

\newcommand\testColorMixing[1]{%
  \noindent Color Model: \texttt{#1}\\
  \selectcolormodel{#1}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \y in {0,10,...,100} {
      \fill[green!\y!yellow] (.1*\y,0) rectangle ++(1,1);
      \fill[yellow!\y!green] (.1*\y,1.1) rectangle ++(1,1);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \par
}

\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

Color Model: \texttt{natural}
\selectcolormodel{natural}

\ttfamily
\printColorSpec{green}
\printColorSpec{yellow}
\medskip\hrule\par\medskip

\printColorSpec{green!0!yellow}
\printColorSpec{green!10!yellow}
\printColorSpec{green!20!yellow}
\hspace*{.3em}\vdots\par
\printColorSpec{green!90!yellow}
\printColorSpec{green!100!yellow}
\medskip\hrule\par\medskip

\printColorSpec{yellow!0!green}
\printColorSpec{yellow!10!green}
\printColorSpec{yellow!20!green}
\hspace*{.3em}\vdots\par
\printColorSpec{yellow!90!green}
\printColorSpec{yellow!100!green}
\medskip\hrule\par\medskip

\testColorMixing{natural} % default
\testColorMixing{rgb}
\testColorMixing{cmyk}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great insight. +1